# Can EJB container be configured to use RMI over SSLIOP?

Tags: java, rmi, ejb-3.1

One of my application has requirement to use RMI over SSLIOP (SSL InterORB Protocol) is it possible? I tried to find some solutions but nothing specific i find for does anyone has used this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the container. It is possible but undocumented within the Sun/Oracle JDK to change the default IIOP socket factory, and the details changed significantly somewhere around 1.5/1.6, but many containers e.g. IBM WebSphere provide their own RMI/IIOP implementations, where the details are different again, and may or may not be documented. And if your clients live outside the container you have another problem again.